# CiviCase tab not showing up on contact summary

Tags: civicase

When I open a case with a contact, the case tab does not show up on their contact summary. The case exists I can edit it through the case dashboard and it creates the correct relationships. I did a smarty debug and there's no tab info for case, so it's not just 'hiding'. I also tried on more than one contact, and more than one contact sub type, no dice.

Any ideas why the case tab doesn't populate? Or where I can go poking to figure it out.

(I'm running civic 4.6.4 on WP 4.4.4)

Comment: Ray - it helps the community if you come back to answers and either critique them or +1 / Accept them

Comment: @petednz-fuzion I do apologize, I'm no longer part of the set up that the above question is part of so I can't verify the below answer. Is there someway to indicate that?

Comment: hi ray. never mind. just that stackexchange keeps pulling this back to top of list because "This question has answers that may be good or bad; the system has marked it active so that they can be reviewed." I verified it by going to http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contact/view?reset=1&cid=202 and seeing Cases, then as per the answer (in reverse) going to /civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/display?reset=1, then going back to cid=202 and confirming the Case tab does not show. Answer seems spot on to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the display preferences (Admin > Customize .. > Display Prefs) and make sure for Viewing Contacts that Cases is selected